# How to upload(multipart upload) large files to Google Cloud Storage using fog gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-storage, fog

For AWS s3 we have the methods with fog to upload large files in chunks `initiate_multipart_upload`, `upload_part` and `complete_multipart_upload` and are working fine. But if I call the methods like `initiate_multipart_upload` with google it is showing error. I think there is no method available for google with fog. How can I upload the files in chunks to Google cloud Storage. Is there any other way/option available to achieve this?.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Google Storage supports this operation via compose, which you can read about here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/compose

Unfortunately this is not yet implemented within fog. Additionally we currently point to the older xml version of the API instead of the new json one (which includes the compose method), so it might take a bit of effort/thought to get that added in. I'd certainly be happy to provide guidance if you would like to try implementing it. In any case, it would be great if you added an issue on github asking for this (and let us know if you are willing to help out). If you are able to take it on, that would probably be the fastest way to get it available, whereas otherwise we can likely find somebody to help on it in time, but hard to say when.

Thanks!